# If $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ constant on each connected component then $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ a constant function on each connected component of $\Omega$. I need to proof that $f$ is continuous.

I've tried using that connected components are closed to use continuity characterization with closed set and many others but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a\in \Omega$. As $\Omega$ is open, for some $r>0$ the open ball $B_r(a)$ is $\subseteq \Omega$. This open ball also belongs to a single connected comopnent. Hence $f$ is constant on this ball, hence continuous at $a$